# Best practice for writing tests that reproduce bugs

Tags: testing, regression

I am struggling a bit with the way how to write tests that reproduce an issue that has not been yet fixed.

Should one write the test and use wrong expectations and once the bug is fixed the developer will see the failure and adjust the expectations or should one just write the test with correct expectations and disable it. Once it is fixed you have to enable it again.

I would prefer the way to define wrong expectations and add the correct ones in comments and once I fix an issue I will immediately get a notification that it fails. If I disable it I won't see it failing and it will probably stay disabled until one will discover this test.

Are there any other ways doing this?

Thanks for your comments.

Martin

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would write a test that reproduces the bug and then fix said bug.

If for whatever reason that is not currently an option I would say that your approach of having the wrong expectations would be better than having an ignored test.  Assuming that you use some clear variable name/ method name / comments that the test is more a placeholder and not the desired outcome.

One thing that I've done is write a test that is a "time bomb" reminder.  I pick a date that is a few weeks/months out from now that I expect to be able to get back to it or have it fixed by.  If I end up having to push the date out 2 or 3 times I end up deleting the test because it must not be that important.

Comment: I like the "time bomb" idea! Thx for sharing!!

Answer (score 0):

as @Jarred said, best way is to write a test that express the correct expectations, check if it fails, then fix production code and see the test passes.

if it's not an option then remember that tests are not only to test but also to document. so write a test that document how your program does actually work. if necessary add a comment to the test. and don't write tests that are ignored - it's pointless. in future you can refactor your code many times, you could accidentally fix this test or introduce even more error in this area. writing tests that are intended to be long term ignored is just a waste of time.

don't be afraid that you will forget about that particular bug/test, just create a ticket in your issue tracking system - that's what it's made for.

if you use a testing framework that supports groups, you can add all those tests to be able to instantly exclude those test if needed.

also i really don't like the concept of 'time bomb tests'. your build MUST be reproducible - that's the fundamental assumption of release management, continuous integration, ability to pass your code to another team etc. tests are not meant to track and remind about the issues, it's the job of the issue tracking system. seriously, don't do it

Comment: Unfortunately, we have some issues that are just minor things but still worth fixing them in the future. Having a test for reproducing it helps at that point the developer. Some of those tests are currently disabled which I really don't like.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I thought about this again. We are using JUnit and it supports defining expectations on exceptions via @Test(expected=Exception.class).

So what one can do is write the test with the desired expectations and define the test with @Test(expected=AssertionError.class). Once the test will be fixed the test starts failing and the developer has to remove the expectation.